# How to launch a process with sudo by ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#, mono, debian, processstartinfo

I have a program in Debian which needs root privileges and myuser has to run it, but I have to do the call from a .NET application (C#) running in mono.
In /etc/sudoers, I have add the line:

```
myuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /myprogram
```

so `sudo ./myprogram` works for myuser.

In. NET I use in my code

```
string fileName = "/myprogram";
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo (fileName);
...
```

How can I do the call "sudo fileName"? It doesn't work by the time... 
thank you, Monique.

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me in a similar situation, and demonstrates passing in multiple arguments:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    Arguments = string.Format("-c \"sudo {0} {1} {2}\"", "/path/to/script", "arg1", arg2)
};

using (var p = Process.Start(psi))
{
    if (p != null)
    {
        var strOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great way to capture stdout too - `RedirectStandardOutput = true` doesn't work with Jariq's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass your program as the argument to the sudo command like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("sudo", "/myprogram");
Process.Start(info);
```